# Are dynamically inserted <script> tags meant to work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have some code where a `<script type="text/javascript">` block is dynamically inserted.

This block contains a function, which has an `<input type="button">` element above it (also dynamically inserted) call it with the `onclick` attribute.

However, it is not working, and Firebug says that the function is not defined when I attempt to click the button.

Is this expectable, and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes, that should work, assuming you're doing it right. Post the code & we'll let you know...

Comment: Did you view the page source and verify that the function is actually inserted as you expect?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "dynamically inserted". Define this please.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: it's fairly obvious to me what he means - how many different ways can you define dynamically inserted?

Comment: Firebug shows the <script> tag, and when I click "Edit HTML..." the JavaScript shows up fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're writing it to an innerHTML property, [it won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) except for in IE when the DEFER attribute is present:

```
scriptParentNode.innerHTML = '<span/><script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">blah();</script>';
```

Your options are, a) use the DOM to create the element and append it:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var sTag = document.createElement("script");
sTag.type = "text/javascript";
sTag.text = "blah();";
head.appendChild(sTag);
```

or b) use document.write at the time your HTML is parsed (but not after!)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">blah();</script>');
  </script>
</head>
```

**EDIT**

Seeing as I was downvoted *apparently* for the information regarding the defer attribute being incorrect, I feel it necessary to post a working example from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(VS.85).aspx).  Whilst it is true that IE removes NoScope elements from the beginning of an innerHTML string, it's possible to work around this by adding a scoped element to the beginning of the HTML string (example updated above):

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT>
function insertScript(){
    var sHTML="<input type=button onclick=" + "go2()" + " value='Click Me'><BR>";
    var sScript="<SCRIPT DEFER>";
    sScript = sScript + "function go2(){ alert('Hello from inserted script.') }";
    sScript = sScript + "</SCRIPT" + ">";
    ScriptDiv.innerHTML = sHTML + sScript;
}    
</SCRIPT>
<BODY onload="insertScript();">
    <DIV ID="ScriptDiv"></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Feel free to actually click the "Show me" button in the MSDN documentation for a working example. [[link](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/insertScript_2.htm)]

Comment: I'm using the DOM method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = blah
```

then no, it won't work.

An easy workaround is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do your insertion, which *will* execute the script in that block.  Just use the `html` function on an element, passing it your HTML/script block.

Comment: Is it just me that doesn't particularly appreciate getting answers like "use xxx library"?  What if he's only writing 5 lines of code, is it really worth the browser downloading and parsing a library to perform a simple function?

Comment: I actually am a jQuery user, however for this specific instance I do not want to use a library

Comment: As am I, it's just that there are a number of scenarios where cross-browser compatibility is not needed (intranets, desktop widgets, etc) and whilst libraries can still make things easier they might sometimes be overkill.  I do wonder if some people know javascript outside of libraries...

Comment: AndyE, I actually agree with you here - having someone tell you "use a library" often isn't very helpful.  However in this particular answer I was speaking purely from experience, and jQuery was what I used to solve the problem; I wasn't aware that the DOM based alternative worked, to be perfectly honest.  At the time there was no answer, so I figured one using jQuery was better than none at all.

Comment: Don't mind me, it was 2am and I had my grumpy head on :-)  I remember, you got your answer out while I was still writing mine and I agree, an answer is an answer at the end of the day and jQuery is always a suitable option for most devs.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically inserted client-side or server-side?

Server-side it'll work - assuming that the server-side call isn't an AJAX postback (Cause then in reality the actual dynamic insertion is still client-side).

Client-side it won't (you can't simply inject java-script into a page after it's already loaded and expect it to execute). You'll have to actually explicitly execute the JavaScript in that case or use a framework like jQuery that'll do that for you.