# Jquery .load and inner jquery .append

Tags: jquery

Ive just started using jquery for the .load ajax functionality. When i load an external page to a specific div it loads fine. inside the external page there is an .append that .appends javascript to the head. This works on the initial load but when i use .load to load it this portion is not showing.

```
//This is the .load for the div
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {

 url = ""+sourceUrl+"";
$(""+elementSelector+"").load(url);
 alert(url);

}

//This is the append in the other page that is embedded in a js 

var cUrl = "http://intensedebate.com/js/genericCommentWrapper2.php?acct="+idcomments_acct+"&postid="+idcomments_post_id+"&title="+idcomments_post_title+"&url="+idcomments_post_url;
alert(cUrl);


commentScript.type = "text/javascript";
commentScript.src = cUrl;

$('head').append(commentScript);
```

**EDIT: The alert(cUrl) runs every time. But the head append isnt rendering.**

Comment: Why on earth are you concatenating empty strings?

Comment: LOL  I got that code off of the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses the `innerHTML` property to append loaded HTML via the `.load()` method:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document was retrieved directly by the browser.

Scripts cannot be inserted using .innerHTML (at least, not in a cross-browser compatible manner), which is why your `.load()` will not execute your script appending script.

Further reading:

- [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)
- [Are dynamically inserted <script> tags meant to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891947/are-dynamically-inserted-script-tags-meant-to-work/1891999#1891999)

Comment: Well all of the other script runs. If i put an alert in their it runs fine but the .append to the header isnt rendering. Is there a better way to handle this ?