# How to deal with different kinds of encoding in the javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, encoding

I recognized that based on a context in which I want to use some parameters, there are at least 4 kinds of encoding that are necessary to avoid corrupted code being executed :

1. Javascript encoding when constructing a javascript code, e.g.

   ```
   var a = "what's up ?"
   var b = "alert('" + a + "');"
   eval(b); // or anything else that executes b as code
   ```
2. URL encoding when using a string as a parameter into the url, e.g.

   ```
   var a = "Bonnie & Clyde";
   var b = "mypage.html?par=" + a;
   window.location.href = b; // or anything else that tries to use b as URL
   ```
3. HTML encoding when using a string as an HTML source of some element, e.g.

   ```
   var a = "<script>alert('hi');</script>";
   b.innerHTML = a; // or anything else that interprets a directly
   ```
4. HTML attribute encoding when using a string as a value of an attribute, e.g.

   ```
   var a = 'alert("hello")';
   var b = '<img onclick="' + a + '" />'; // or anything else that uses a as a (part of) a tag's attribute
   ```

While in the ASP.NET codebehind I'm aware of ways to encode the string in all 4 cases (using e.g. `DataContractJsonSerializer`, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode`), it would be quite interesting to know whether there are some utilities that I could use directly from javascript to encode / decode strings in these 4 cases.

Comment: In case 3, are you trying to avoid the JavaScript from being executed altogether?

Comment: exactly, i want the code to be displayed at the page in that case

Answer (score 3):

Case 2 can be dealt with using *encodeURIComponent()*, as [danp suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666538/how-to-deal-with-different-kinds-of-encoding-in-the-javascript/3666567#3666567).

Case 3 [won't execute the script in most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891947/are-dynamically-inserted-script-tags-meant-to-work/1891999#1891999).  If you want the output to the document to be `<script>...</script>`, you should edit the text content of the element instead:

```
var a = "<script>alert('hi');</script>";
if ("textContent" in b)
    b.textContent = a; // W3C DOM
else
    b.innerText = a; // Internet Explorer <=8
```

Cases 1, and 4 aren't really encoding issues, they're sanitation issues.  Encoding the strings passed to these functions would probably cause a syntax error or just result in a string value that isn't assigned to anything.  Sanitizing usually involves looking for certain patterns and either allowing the action or disallowing it - it's safer to have a whitelist than a blacklist (that sounds terrible!).

Internet Explorer 8 has an interesting function called [*window.toStaticHTML()*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848922(VS.85).aspx) that will remove any script content from a HTML string.  Very useful for sanitizing HTML before inserting into the DOM.  Unfortunately, it's proprietary so you won't find this function in other browsers.

Comment: Re case 3 I believe the OP's goal is not to avoid JavaScript execution but simply to have the html encoded (see his comment to the question).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript function `escape(..)` for some of these purposes.

e: actually forget! sorry, it's a deprecated function - `encodeURI()`, `decodeURI()` etc are the way forward! Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions).

> escape and unescape functions do not
>   work properly for non-ASCII characters
>   and have been deprecated. In
>   JavaScript 1.5 and later, use
>   encodeURI, decodeURI,
>   encodeURIComponent, and
>   decodeURIComponent.
>
> The escape and unescape functions let
>   you encode and decode strings. The
>   escape function returns the
>   hexadecimal encoding of an argument in
>   the ISO Latin character set. The
>   unescape function returns the ASCII
>   string for the specified hexadecimal
>   encoding value.encoding value.

Comment: actually, I believe encodeURIComponent() would cover exactly the case 2.. only 3 cases left :)