# Why doesn't jQuery's $.get() insert script elements into the DOM?

Tags: jquery

I am using `$.get()` to retrieve an HTML snippet from a remote server and insert that snippet into the DOM. The snippet contains several basic HTML elements and a script element. All of the basic elements get inserted, but the script element does not.

**Example snippet:**

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript that will work with the HTML in the snippet
</script>
```

I have verified that the script element is in the retrieved snippet by looking at the resources retrieved in Chrome's web inspector. So, why doesn't `$.get()` insert the script element and is it possible to do what I am wanting to do?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I was retrieving the HTML snippet with `$.get()` and inserting it into the DOM with `$().html(data)`.

Comment: Why do you need the script element?  Normally you just need it to execute, is your situation different?

Comment: The script contains functions for handling a form element that is included in the snippet. The functions are to be bound to things like a select changing value and the form being submitted. None of this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script element should be inserted, just as static content - the script will not execute.  When you use *html()* to insert html, it maps to each element's *innerHTML* property.  Historically, browsers don't execute script elements inserted this way (with the exception of IE [in certain circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891947/are-dynamically-inserted-script-tags-meant-to-work/1891999#1891999)).

This is also reflected in the [definition of innerHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) in the draft HTML 5 specification:

> Note: script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.

If you want to execute the script, you could look up the element and *eval()* its text, or create a new script element from the text and insert it into the DOM properly.

Answer (score 1):

Script elements are not binded to document when you do this.
You need to insert the script yourself.

One way to do that is by calling a callback function that parsers your return html and insert the script manually. Like this one:
`

```
_insertScripts: function(html) {
        var sfrag = '<script[^>]*>([\\S\\s]*?)<\/script>';
        var matchAll = new RegExp(sfrag, 'img');
        var matchOne = new RegExp(sfrag, 'im');
        if(html.match(matchAll)) {
            $.map(html.match(matchAll), function(script) {
                eval( (script.match(matchOne) || ['', ''])[1] );
            });
        }
    }
```

`

I've seen some solutions that use the live() function from jQuery also, but I'm not sure on how it works.