# jQuery .get doesn't load <script>

Tags: jquery, get, load

I'm having a major problem here and I'm running out of options. I hope someone can help me.

I have a link that loads content in a div after it is clicked. I'm using jQuery .get to retrieve the content (which by the way is hosted on the same server). This is what I have:

```
<a href="#" id="button">Link</a>
<div id="box"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $.get("includes/data.php", function(data) {
            $("#box").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the content of data.php. No doctype, no head, no body:

```
<div class="info-box-content">
    <script>map.findMovieClipByString('map')</script>
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <h2>Address</h2>
    <p>More content here</p>
</div>
```

The tricks works as expected but the script line won't load. It looks like it gets stripped off automatically. I tried to add a doctype, head and body, but nothing.

Does .get prevent scripts to be loaded? Is there a way around it?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't jQuery's $.get() insert script elements into the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686043/why-doesnt-jquerys-get-insert-script-elements-into-the-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that it doesn't get inserted into the DOM, then you find this comment helpful: http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-67912032  JQuery seems to evaluate script tags separately, instead of inserting them into the DOM.

Comment: Interesting indeed. I wish the thread would offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `load()` which like `$.get` is a shortcut method for `$.ajax`. `load()` typically works fine loading scripts

```
   $("#box").load( "includes/data.php");
```

Comment: It loads everything except for the script. Thank s for the hint though.

Comment: something wrong then, never had problems with load...are errors thrown in console?

Comment: No errors. Based on what swajak replied below (http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-67912032) that would explain my problem.

Comment: read the docs for load..section regarding script execution  http://api.jquery.com/load/ Point being, it should execute

Comment: Someone just posted that 5 minutes after my post. Interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686043/why-doesnt-jquerys-get-insert-script-elements-into-the-dom

Comment: promise you I have used load many many times with scripts in response with no issues

Comment: I tried again but no go. Whatever script line I add to the code, it removes right away. But thanks for your help Charlie. I need to find a new solution.

Comment: check headers and things like that, no idea why a header would cause problems but never know