# make javascript added by setting innerHTML fire

Tags: javascript

I have a project where I need to run code that is set using `innerHTML` like so:

```
element.innerHTML = '<script>alert("something")</script>';
```

**When I do this, the code doesn't run. What can I do to make the code run?**

*Thank you! If you down vote, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Comment: Why would you do this?  Why not just execute whatever code you need.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work

Comment: Short answer is no, check this thread for the same scenario. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891947/are-dynamically-inserted-script-tags-meant-to-work