# Sending javascript variable axios to php

Tags: php, axios

Im trying to send a post request with axios to php. Im a bit lost, still new to this stuff. 
in my react.js I have this. Im trying to send the value of searchTerm

```
axios.post(`http://www.fake.com/script.php`,{
  searchTerm:'test',
})
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
})
```

In the script.php file which I have hosted on my site, I have this:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $searchTerm = $_POST["searchTerm"];
    echo $searchTerm;
    echo '<script>console.log('.$searchTerm.')</script>';
}
```

nothing is echoed on the actual page.

On the console, I have 3 things.

1. XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "http://www.fake.com/script.php"
2. data object, which includes config,data,headers,etc.
3. XHR finished loading: POST "http://www.fake.com/script.php"

Comment: So what happens? What do you see in your console?

Comment: I just edited the OP to show that

Comment: That's the network traffic logging. What do you see in your _Console_? You should expect either the result of `console.log(response)` or `console.log(error)`. Perhaps try giving them some labels to help identification, eg `console.log('response', response)` and `console.error(error)`

Comment: I just did that, Im getting a response, which is the data object #2 on the op. But shouldnt it also console.log the actual search term as I specified in the script.php. Seems like maybe the php file isnt receiving the searchterm

Comment: No, the response from your PHP is just text / HTML. It will be in the `response.data` property. You haven't inserted it into your document and even then, it's not going to just execute the `<script>` blocks (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1891947/283366)

Comment: Response.data is empty

Comment: Is your PHP / HTTP server set up to respond correctly to the `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: response.config.data  "{"searcTerm":"test"}"   and the actual obejct of response[config,data,headers,request,status etc].... response.data:"" is empty.... Im not sure what OPTIONS request means, but I have tested my site by sending an axios get request to a php file there, and i returned the data from the php file with no issues.

Comment: I googled that, and I think your talking about CORS ?..if so < I am using a Cors chrome extension to allow me to make these calls " Allow-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Might want to try `echo var_export($_POST);` to see what the script is getting.

Comment: I believe i got back array() ...but Im getting a 500 internal server error now that Im trying to troubleshoot, not sure if this is caused because I have tweaked and uploaded many the script.php file many times since this post to try and make it work

Comment: Var_export($_POST)  , the response data is “array()” ... and if I $data=$_POST; var_dump($data) , the response data is “array(0){}”